Azure Synapse can't resolve vnet integrated function app url
I got a synapse instance with managed private network enabled and a bunch of services connected through managed private endpoint that is working as expected.
However, recently we have added a azure function which is vnet integrated and create a managed private endpoint to the function app but are unable to resolve the fqdn, either using web requests or the function app activity in the synapse pipelines.
This function app have been configured similarly with private dns zones, and is reachable through our VPN without issues. This is only a problem in synapse.
I did notice that when created a linked service or any of the calls on synapse, there is no way of actually pointing the traffic through that managed endpoint in a similar fashion to SQL endpoints, so i feel like i'm missing a step somewhere, but documentation is nowhere to be found.
These are the errors im getting
Synapse Web Request
{
    "errorCode": "2108",
    "message": "Error calling the endpoint 'https://func-xxxx.appserviceenvironment.net'. Response status code: 'NA - Unknown'. More details: Exception message: 'NA - Unknown [ClientSideException] The remote name could not be resolved: 'https://func-xxxx.appserviceenvironment.net''.\r\nRequest didn't reach the server from the client. This could happen because of an underlying issue such as network connectivity, a DNS failure, a server certificate validation or a timeout. ",
    "failureType": "UserError",
    "target": "Web1",
    "details": []
}

Synapse Function Activity
{
    "errorCode": "3610",
    "message": "There was an error while calling endpoint with error message - 'The remote name could not be resolved: 'https://func-xxxx.appserviceenvironment.net''.",
    "failureType": "UserError",
    "target": "Azure Function1",
    "details": []
}

Does anyone know how to successfully establish a private connection between the managed network synapse instance and the private function app?

I found a workaround to this issue.
The issue seems to stem from the fact that it's using an ASE, meaning that the function app itself isn't actually rescinding within the VNET it self.
The work around i managed to implement was to deploy an application gateway as a proxy in between with the backend pointing to the function app.
Once deployed, create a private link service.
This private link service can now be chosen to create a managed private endpoint against from Synapse.
Once approven, the function app can be reached and queried through a web request in synapse pipelines on the managed private endpoint IP address to the application gateway and a header of host=${full fqdn of function app}
